# Sleep Timer with MPMusicPlayerController

Tags: ios, nstimer, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'm working on an iOS app that uses MPMusicPlayerController to play audio from the iTunes library.

Is it possible to create a timer that will run while the app is in the background? I would like to implement a sleep timer. NSTimer seems like it is out of the question, or rather limited to 3 minutes. Are there any other options I could try?

Currently, I have this in my App Delegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                                     withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
                                           error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the app running in the background while using MPMusicPlayerController you can play silence in the background. This is probably a bad idea...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                                     withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
                                           error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"silence" ofType:@"m4a"];
    self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path] error:nil];
    self.player.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [self.player play];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NSTimer is not at all out of the question. You cannot *start* a timer in the background, but you can certainly use one. But of course you have to stay running in the background in some other way. For example, if you are already playing music as we go into the background, and you have configured your app for background music playing, then you will keep running in the background: the music will continue playing, so the timer, *if it was running when we went into the background*, will continue running.

Comment: I have the background mode for "audio & airplay" enabled. But it seems like when you use MPMusicPlayerController it does not stay activated because it's technically using the "systemPlayer". Even if I use "applicationPlayer" I get the same issue.

Comment: I wonder if I can play silence in AVPlayer ontop of MPMusicPlayer to keep in running in the background...

Comment: "But it seems like when you use MPMusicPlayerController it does not stay activated" Did you remember to set your app's audio category to Playback?

Comment: Yes, I've seen the "play silence" trick as a way of continuing to run in the background. Sneaky! I see why your "mix" setting is needed. You might want to pull that out of your question and give it as an answer; it deserves to be shown off.

Comment: I'm wondering if the "play silence" trick will work because if A: I'm playing audio anyways... and B: I'll only use it during the sleep timer.